# SPARK load big dataset, what persist level to choose?

Tags: apache-spark, memory, bigdata, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have to proceed about 500 GB compressed data. 
I have to do different sort of filtration of this data. 
I am quite unsure in my persist actions performed on RDD at Spark.
Here is my code below:

```
val mypath = paths(0)

val df = sparkSession.read
  .parquet(mypath)
  .as[SafegraphRawData]
  // Persist here since uncompressed JAVA objects not fit in memory
  .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

val filter: BaseFilter = new BaseFilter()

val upperProcessingDate = processingDate.plusDays(appConf.duration)
LOG.info(s"Filter between $processingDate and $upperProcessingDate")
val lowerTimeBound = processingDate.getMillis();
val upperTimeBound = upperProcessingDate.getMillis()-1;

LOG.info(s"Number of partitions: " + df.rdd.getNumPartitions)
val rddPoints= df
  // This transform will reduce data
  .filter(dateRange(_, lowerTimeBound, upperTimeBound))
  // So repartition here to be able perform shuffle operations later
  .repartition(nrInputPartitions)
  // another transformations and minor filtration
  .map(parse)
  .filter(filter.IsValid(_, deviceStageMetricService, providerdevicelist, sparkSession))
  .map(convert)

LOG.info(s"Number of partitions: " + rddPoints.rdd.getNumPartitions)
// Since we will perform count and partitionBy actions, compute all above transformations
val dsPoints = rddPoints.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
val totalPoints = dsPoints.count()
LOG.info(s"in safegraph.load: totalpoints  = $totalPoints")

dsPoints.show()
LOG.info(s"show results...")
dsPoints
// ...
val nrOutputPartitions = appConf.getNrOutputPartitions()

var exportRdd = stage
if (nrOutputPartitions > 0) {
  LOG.info(s"Coalescing parquet preExportRdd to ${appConf.getNrOutputPartitions()} partitions")
  exportRdd = stage.coalesce(nrOutputPartitions)
}

 exportRdd.toDF().write.partitionBy("y", "m", "d", "r", "p")
  .format("parquet")
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .save(appConf.getS3DestinationUrl())

exportRdd.unpersist()
```

I am expect this code to produce some simple DAG graph but for count action perform I get Job with 3 stages and big DAG that I cannot understand.

[image: DAG for Count operation]

Stage 12 is pretty straitforward and it performs all transformations and persist, but why it is fully repeated at stage 13? 
Also which storage level better to choose? Why anyone would need to use DISK only, if MEMORY_AND_DISK is in place?